# How to run ChromeOS apps on Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome-os

Is it possible to run ChromeOS apps on Linux? I tried searching it in my browser but only "How to run Linux apps on ChromeOS?" appeared in results. ChromeOS is just Google's Linux distro so I think it should be possible. Many apps, however, have only for example Windows and ChromeOS version downloadable from Play store. Can I install Play store on my Linux?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think chromeOS apps differ much from chrome apps which can be accessed from chrome browser - go to `chrome://apps/` .

```
Is it possible to run ChromeOS apps on Linux?
```

Not that directly but yes

Most chrome apps are just Web Apps and can be accessed through web browsers and for more chromeOS like exerience use chrome browser itself.

Some screenshots -

[image]

```
ChromeOS is just Google's Linux distro so I think it should be possible.
```

It is !! but with lot of differences. You can simply tell this by looking at partition table of chromeOS.It need 12 partitions to work as opposed to linux which can run on one partition.Ofc there are also other major differences which i am not pointing out here !!

```
Many apps, however, have only for example Windows and ChromeOS version downloadable from Play store. Can I install Play store on my Linux?
```

Do not cleary understood what you mean by `downloadable` but you cannot run android apps directly on Windows directly.

Alternatives :

1. Chromium OS

[quick-start-guide](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/quick-start-guide)

**No official Chromium OS images** are available. You will have to build chromium os yourself.

**No android/play-store support**

2. Android studio

emulate android device and allows user install android apps from playstore but it is just android **not chromeOS**

3. Android x86

**unofficial** porting of Google's Android mobile operating system

just android **not chromeOS**

4. Chromefy/brunch/FydeOS/ArnoldTheBats-ChromiumOS {***Unofficial***}

[Chromefy](https://github.com/imperador/chromefy)

- chromeOS
- has play-store support

[brunch](https://github.com/sebanc/brunch)

- chromeOS
- has play-store support
- actively maintained

[FydeOS](https://fydeos.com/)

[ArnoldTheBats-ChromiumOS](https://chromium.arnoldthebat.co.uk/index.php?dir=special&order=modified&sort=desc)

- No playstore support

[Cloudready](https://www.neverware.com/#intro)

- ChromeOS like
- No playstore support

Comment: I know it is possible to run android apps on Linux (for example with anbox). My point was whether you can run apps from ChromeOS play store on Linux. Not Android play store.

Comment: @yomol777 ChromeOS play store ??  i think you mean chrome web store !! Anyway i think i answered your question already !!

Comment: Hmm... I have only extensions and themes in my Chrome Web Store. Where is the Chrome Web Store with apps?